# How to put recovery mode on jetson xavier agx without interface?

Tags: boot, mode, recovery, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

can someone help me to put my jetson xavier agx mode to recovery mode, I tried from micro usb to computer, but it doesnt work, computer doesnt detect jetson, please point me the istruction to put recovery mode

I tried from micro usb to usb version with my computer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Start with power off. Connect power supply if not yet done.
   Connect a USB cable from host into micro-USB connector of AGX Xavier.
2. Press and hold ForceRecovery button (the middle one).
3. Press and release Power button.
4. Wait for 3 seconds
5. Release force recovery button.

Then your AGX Xavier should be in recovery mode.
From host, lsusb should now show the Jeston as a device from NVIDIA Corp.

Note that recovery mode doesn't restore any default state, it just puts your jetson in a mode where it could be reflashed from host (using SDKM or flash.sh script).

Answer (score 0):

From [Nvidia documentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/embedded/secure/jetson/xavier/docs/nv_jetson_agx_xavier_developer_kit_user_guide.pdf?EaxdLvIsm-LrgIdz419IPuEY_jTN10ZnPID3XSdXtmaybHZPFd-a0ca6oZ0sRd___7u1ij9p6dJvvhqUp7Mea5EMPfyHYLdhtOTdcs6lLLL5qP4UkY6sTWS0iyHkO49MG-bgBohQ1KBfVyU68cVfk7v8q1IPUapd2C4ND-1fPB9zyFiXxyEfujWeytT0AHj7I3veaT6LoZMllg==&t=eyJscyI6IndlYnNpdGUiLCJsc2QiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXIubnZpZGlhLmNvbS9jdWRhLXRvb2xraXQtYXJjaGl2ZSJ9) -

1. Use the included USB cable to connect the Linux host computer to the front **USB Type-C** connector on the developer kit.
2. Connect the included AC adapter to the developer kit’s DC jack and plug it in to a source of AC power.
3. Press and hold down the Force Recovery button.
4. Press and hold down the Power button.
5. Release both buttons